# Convert Datetime2 to smalldatetime trigger

Tags: c#, sql

I need to convert datetime2 to smalldatetime Can someone give me a simple example of how to convert datetime2 to smalldatetime trigger

I figured a trigger was the way to do this but haven't gotten the
syntax right. Can someone please show me how? I've never written a
trigger before.

Comment: @wterbeek
 
    Declare @ dt Smalldatetime,@ dtTime  
    Select @ dtTime = inserted.BIRTH 
     select @ dt=CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME,@ dtTime,103)  
select @ dt

Comment: check the below answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @datetime2 datetime2 = '12-10-25 12:32:10.1234567';
DECLARE @smalldatetime smalldatetime = @datetime2;

SELECT @datetime2 AS '@datetime2', @smalldatetime AS '@smalldatetime';
```

Result :

```
> @datetime2                  @datetime
> --------------------------- -----------------------
> 2025-12-10 12:32:10.1234567 2025-12-10 12:32:10.123
> 
> (1 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: I need to change the type of the data when data inserted.
I wrote this code but does not work
CREATE TRIGGER CustomerTrigger
ON [GENIUS3].[CUSTOMER_EXTENSION]
FOR INSERT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @ dtTime datetime2
SELECT @ dtTime = ID_DATE_OF_BIRTH FROM INSERTED
SELECT CAST(@ dtTime AS smalldatetime )
END

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER CustomerTrigger ON [GENIUS3].[CUSTOMER_EXTENSION] FOR INSERT AS BEGIN DECLARE @ dtTime datetime2 SELECT @ dtTime = ID_DATE_OF_BIRTH FROM INSERTED SELECT @dtTime AS smalldatetime END check this